# my discord bot works well for a while but then "failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, heroku-api

I've tried different approaches and looked at all the other replies but i dont know how to adress it

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-03-19T09:15:18.022903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-03-19T09:15:18.059850+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-03-19T09:15:18.210022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-03-19T09:15:18.331083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const OpenAI = require('openai-api');
const openai = new OpenAI(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY);
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

let prompt =`text here`;

client.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    prompt += `You: ${message.content}\n`;
    (async () => {
        const gptResponse = await openai.complete({
            engine: 'davinci',
            prompt: prompt,
            maxTokens: 80,
            temperature: 0.7,
            topP: 1,
            presencePenalty: 0,
            frequencyPenalty: 0,
            bestOf: 1,
            n: 1,
            stream: false,
            stop: ['\n', '\n\n']
        });
        message.reply(`${gptResponse.data.choices[0].text.substring(5)}`);
        prompt += `${gptResponse.data.choices[0].text}\n`;
    })();
});     

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

my procfile is empty but it still works for 60 seconds
any ideas?
edit: THINGS I TRIED THAT DONT WORK
i tried changing procfile to contain

```
worker:  node index.js
```

procfile to `worker: java -jar build/libs/*.jar`

Comment: "i tried changing procfile"—this file must be called `Procfile`, _exactly_. It can't be `procfile` or `ProcFile` or `Procfile.txt` or anything else. You've called it `procfile` twice; make sure you've named it correctly, then commit and redeploy.

Comment: Using the `Procfile` to set up a `worker` instead of a `web` process _should_ fix the issue. Though I'm not clear why you tried a Node.js command and also a Java command...

Answer (score 0):

Use the name `Procfile` instead of `procfile`, otherwise heroku doesn't learns that you need worker process and not the default web process.